# Entity Framework timeout when accessing a specific data entity

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I created a WCF service, to link my database to my front-end app.

Everything works fine on my computer but when my friends try to use it on a specific call, they get a timeout.

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

Here is the line where they get timed out:

`consumersModelList = dbContext.dbContext.consumer.ToList();`

My database doesn't have many values so it's not a LINQ timeout. The connection to the database works fine because any other calls that doesn't use this table works fine.

I have no idea what's the difference between mine and their.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: How many Consumer records are there? Doing ToList is getting all records from that table and also enabling tracking on these entities. Do a Count() and see how many you have and report back your findings.

Comment: Also [so] is an English only site so if you have an Exception you should post the Exception as text in your question but please ensure the Exception is in English *as generated by the program*, do not translate it yourself as this makes searching for previous answers much more difficult.

Comment: Sorry about the image. The table only have 2 rows so the time out doens't come from Linq

Comment: Please include the full Exception text in your question.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: I recommend you run Sql Profiler to capture the incoming query *and* the execution plan. You can then analize the plan to see what is going on. An other alternative is to see Recent Expensive Queries in SSMS. It might be a locking issue (deadlock). It could also be too many records in that table. It is hard to say without doing some more investigation on your end.

Comment: The queries in SQL Profiler are the same and it return a response, so i don't think it could come from SSMS. There are only 2 rows and the calls on others tables that have more values work fine.

Answer (score 0):

this probably because your computer not configured to enable remote access to your SQL server database. you should enable your firewall and configured the required port
and you should do the following steps :

1. enable TCP/IP connection to your computer :

a. go to SQL Server Configuration Manager.
b. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, expand SQL Server Network Configuration, and then click Protocols .
c. In the list of protocols, right-click the protocol you want to enable (TCP/IP), and then click Enable.

2. Configuring a Fixed Port:

a. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, expand SQL Server Network Configuration, and then click on the server instance you want to configure.

b. In the right pane, double-click TCP/IP.

c. In the TCP/IP Properties dialog box, click the IP Addresses tab.

e. In the TCP Port box of the IPAll section, type an available port number. For this tutorial, we will use 49172.

f. Click OK to close the dialog box, and click OK to the warning that the service must be restarted.

g. In the left pane, click SQL Server Services.

h. In the right pane, right-click the instance of SQL Server, and then click Restart. When the Database Engine restarts, it will listen on port 49172.

3. Opening Ports in the Firewall

a. On the Start menu, click Run, type WF.msc, and then click OK.

b. In Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, in the left pane, right-click Inbound Rules, and then click New Rule in the action pane.

c. In the Rule Type dialog box, select Port, and then click Next.

d. In the Protocol and Ports dialog box, select TCP. Select Specific local ports, and then type the port number of the instance of the Database Engine. Type 1433 for the default instance. Type 49172 if you are configuring a named instance and configured a fixed port in the previous task. Click Next.

e. In the Action dialog box, select Allow the connection, and then click Next.

f. In the Profile dialog box, select any profiles that describe the computer connection environment when you want to connect to the Database Engine, and then click Next.

g. In the Name dialog box, type a name and description for this rule, and then click Finish.

4. Connecting to the Database Engine from Another Computer :

To connect to the Database Engine from another computer

a. On a second computer that contains the SQL Server client tools, log in with an account authorized to connect to SQL Server, and open Management Studio.

b. In the Connect to Server dialog box, confirm Database Engine in the Server type box.

c. In the Server name box, type tcp: to specify the protocol, followed by the computer name, a comma, and the port number. To connect to the default instance, the port 1433 is implied and can be omitted; therefore, type tcp:<computer_name>. In our example for a named instance, type tcp:<computer_name>,4917.

this ansewer based on Microsft documentation and the refrence link are :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks for you answer. We all have the databse in local so i don't think the problem is here :(